# Не могу преобразовать .csv в dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Не получается преобразовать данные .csv в датафрейм. Не выходит из-за `;` в файле видимо.
Пробовал через `data = data['1;2;3;4;5;6'].str.split(';',expand=True)` но тоже не выходит (хотя там не 6 колонок, просто цифры 1-6 в примере указал сейчас)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Пример данных:

```
70000706    +03:00  6,37E+17    1,93E+18    122000  281 2   
70000706    +03:00  6,37E+17    1,93E+18    121930  307 2   Active
70000706    +03:00  6,37E+17    1,93E+18    121930  307 2   
70000706    +03:00  6,37E+17    1,93E+18    122000  279 2   Active
```

Хотелось бы получить датафрейм с столбцами название которых 1, 2, 3, 4 и т.п.
Если есть возможность то также как то исправить время и дату. (там где `6,37E+17  1,93E+18`)

[Файл тут](https://dropmefiles.com/psTQM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно указать опции чтения `csv`-файла. Подробнее по ссылке https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

У Вас разделители десятичной части запятые, а разделители колонок `;`. После установки дополнительных опций все читается без ошибок.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('time.txt', index_col=False, decimal=',', delimiter=';', header=None)
```

Comment: `data[4].plot()`